# How can I find out which applications on my computer use .NET?

Tags: dependencies, uninstall, application, dotnet-framework

I would like to clean-up some of my computers. There are multiple versions of the .NET framework installed in parallel (2.0, 3.0, 3.5). How can I find out if one of my local applications is still using these frameworks? And how can I find out *which* applications are using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, because there's nothing to say an application has to register with .NET or anything. It just uses it - the application doesn't even need to be installed.

Besides which - having multiple version of .NET is absolutely fine.

Comment: OK. So is there a way to tell that a *running* application is using a specific .NET version? Like "command X shows it has loaded Y.dll so it uses .NET 3.5".